# Сделать горизонтальное заполнение, внутри блока

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть код, его задача при наведении на слово " html " выводить скрытый блок длительностью 22 секунды с каким то словом внутри, как возможно реализовать, чтобы при появлении этого блока он заполнялся внутри за определенное время другим цветом слева на право и на половину и было видно слово, примерно как то так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или тут нужен `javascript` ?

```css
.name:hover ~ .block {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 1s ease-out 0s;
}

.block {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 250px; bottom: 30px;
  width: 200px; height: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 2s ease-out 1s,opacity 1s ease-out 22s;
}

.block::before {
  content: '';
 position: absolute;
}

.name {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
  left: 150px; top: 25px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <div class="name">html</div>
  <div class="block">Магия</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ни какая там не магия - смотрите и js тут не причём

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.block div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 4s linear;
}

.item:hover .block div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <p>HTML</p>
  <div class="block">
    <div>
      html
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Так , это понятно, но проблема в том,что нужно это делать в блоке который появляется и тут у меня возникают трудности с тем что сам border начинает растягиваться

Comment: @Анкор  у меня в примере что то  растягивается ?

Comment: Нет у вас не растягивалось, вы просто видимо меня не поняли,нужно при наведении на надпись "html" чтобы в скрытом блоке проигрывалась это заполнение  с задержкой

Comment: @Анкор понял - минут через 20-30 проверишь я переделаю

Comment: Буду очень благодарен вам

Comment: @Анкор  исправил - проверь

Comment: Да все верно,я как то и не додумался) Спасибо вам!

Comment: @Анкор  https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/PoYGwvv  вот здесь я ease поменял и ещё интереснее выглядит